# Apache Nifi - Cannot start Nifi due to /opt/nifi/nifi-current cound not be created

Tags: java, apache-nifi

I got the Nifi extracted to /opt/nifi/nifi-current
and start it with /bin/nifi.sh start

The log as below:

```
Starting NiFi service

Java home: /home/dev/.sdkman/candidates/java/current
NiFi home: /opt/nifi/nifi-current

Bootstrap Config File: /opt/nifi/nifi-current/conf/bootstrap.conf

Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: /opt/nifi/nifi-current could not be created
    at org.apache.nifi.util.file.FileUtils.ensureDirectoryExistAndCanAccess(FileUtils.java:85)
    at org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.RunNiFi.getBootstrapFile(RunNiFi.java:453)
    at org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.RunNiFi.getStatusFile(RunNiFi.java:464)
    at org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.RunNiFi.loadProperties(RunNiFi.java:477)
    at org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.RunNiFi.getCurrentPort(RunNiFi.java:583)
    at org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.RunNiFi.start(RunNiFi.java:1118)
    at org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.RunNiFi.main(RunNiFi.java:294)
```

Check RunNifi show that it check for /opt/nifi/nifi-current path with this piece of code:

```
   protected File getBootstrapFile(final Logger logger, String directory, String defaultDirectory, String fileName) throws IOException {

        final File confDir = bootstrapConfigFile.getParentFile();
        final File nifiHome = confDir.getParentFile();

        String confFileDir = System.getProperty(directory);

        final File fileDir;

        if (confFileDir != null) {
            fileDir = new File(confFileDir.trim());
        } else {
            fileDir = new File(nifiHome, defaultDirectory);
        }

        FileUtils.ensureDirectoryExistAndCanAccess(fileDir);
        final File statusFile = new File(fileDir, fileName);
        logger.debug("Status File: {}", statusFile);
        return statusFile;
    }
```

```
    public static void ensureDirectoryExistAndCanAccess(final File dir) throws IOException {
        if (dir.exists() && !dir.isDirectory()) {
            throw new IOException(dir.getAbsolutePath() + " is not a directory");
        } else if (!dir.exists()) {
            final boolean made = dir.mkdirs();
            if (!made) {
                throw new IOException(dir.getAbsolutePath() + " could not be created");
            }
        }
        if (!(dir.canRead() && dir.canWrite())) {
            throw new IOException(dir.getAbsolutePath() + " directory does not have read/write privilege");
        }
    }
```

But this seem wrong as:

- the folder is exist but the logic still jump into the throw case
- permission is ok (I change owner and permissions of the folder)

What I could do further to resolve this ?

- Tried to start Nifi with nifi.sh start
- Set all the owner and permission

Answer (score 0):

Permissions issues like this could be related to the conf/bootstrap.conf runas.
The runas must be set to a user that does have permissions.  This might be why it's having a permissions issue on creating the dir.

For reference: https://nifi.apache.org/documentation/v2/
In Admin Guide go to Bootstrap Properties.  You'll see an explanation as to what I'm referring to above.